# Rails 3 redirect to external page with parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have this link:

```
railsapp/api/details.php?id=1&app=dvd
```

That I need to redirecto to another page in an external non-rails server:

```
non-railsapp/api/details.php?id=1&app=dvd
```

If I put this in the routes.rb file:

```
  match '/api/details.php' => redirect("non-railsapp/api/details.php")
```

The redirection will work, but the parameters will not be passed. What magic needs to be there so that the params are passed as well?

In Fact, what would be great would be to be able to redirect everything after the `/api/` to the external site with all parameters. That would make my life a lot easier.

I've read the documentation on Rails Routing but cannot find any examples of something like this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
get "/api/details.php/:id/:app" => redirect{ |p, req| "non-railsapp/api/details.php/#{p[:id]}/#{p[:app]}" }
```

**Edit**:

You could also make the parameters optional:

```
get "/api/details.php(/:id(/:app))" => redirect{ |p, req| "non-railsapp/api/details.php(/#{p[:id]}(/#{p[:app]}))" }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this results in the following error: `No route matches [GET] "/api/details.php"`. One I've gotten a lot trying to figure this out.

Comment: No, the parameters are definitely not optional. Also, making the parameters optional will not fix the fact that the error is about the details.php page not having a route.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

> url = URI("http://www.google.com/")
>
> url.query = URI.encode_www_form(:q => "query")
>
> #redirecting to http://www.google.com/?q=query
>
> redirect_to url.to_s